# Why delete the SQLite & xml folder in WaxApplication on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios

I try to follow the tutor below to build my 1st iOS app step by step
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-wax/

But I'm quite confused by the step
"Open the wax/lib/extensions/ folder in your WaxApplication project folder. Delete the SQLite & xml folder pictured below"

what's wrong with these 2 folders? If anything wrong then why these 2 folders in the default package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that there were some functions pulled out of the main wax files. These two packages depended on these functions.

I do not know why they were pulled, but if you dig up an old wax version you can put them back in like I did.

(I am away from my mac right now so I cannot tell you which files were affected)

Comment: Did you manage to find exactly which functions were pulled? If not, I can add it later this evening when I get home.